# SSH local port forwarding hangs while connecting

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, port-forwarding

I'm trying to establish local port forwarding, but I have come across two difficulties:

When using the `ssh -vL 1083:127.0.0.1:22 akveton2@cms904usr -N`

command,  I get this error:

> bind: Cannot assign requested address

I have googled around a bit and have since found that if this line is included in the debug output, it is trying to connect using IPv6:

> debug1: Local forwarding listening on ::1 port 1083.

I have since added the -4 argument to the command, so the bind error is not being printed anymore, but now the connection hangs after entering the password. What could the problem be? Here is the log:

```
[akveton@lxplus070 ~]$ ssh -vL 1083:127.0.0.1:1083 akveton2@cms904usr -N
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to cms904usr [137.138.251.206] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /afs/cern.ch/user/a/akveton/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /afs/cern.ch/user/a/akveton/.ssh/identity-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /afs/cern.ch/user/a/akveton/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /afs/cern.ch/user/a/akveton/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /afs/cern.ch/user/a/akveton/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /afs/cern.ch/user/a/akveton/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /afs/cern.ch/user/a/akveton/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /afs/cern.ch/user/a/akveton/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 1.99, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<2048<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'cms904usr' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /afs/cern.ch/user/a/akveton/.ssh/known_hosts:13
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Server not found in Kerberos database

debug1: Authentications that can continue: gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
akveton2@cms904usr's password: 
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
debug1: Local connections to LOCALHOST:1083 forwarded to remote address 127.0.0.1:1083
debug1: Local forwarding listening on 127.0.0.1 port 1083.
debug1: channel 0: new [port listener]
debug1: Local forwarding listening on ::1 port 1083.
bind: Cannot assign requested address
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
^Cdebug1: channel 0: free: port listener, nchannels 1
Killed by signal 2.
[akveton@lxplus070 ~]$ ssh -v4L 1083:127.0.0.1:22 akveton2@cms904usr -N^C
[akveton@lxplus070 ~]$ ssh -v4L 1083:127.0.0.1:1083 akveton2@cms904usr -N
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to cms904usr [137.138.251.206] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /afs/cern.ch/user/a/akveton/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /afs/cern.ch/user/a/akveton/.ssh/identity-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /afs/cern.ch/user/a/akveton/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /afs/cern.ch/user/a/akveton/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /afs/cern.ch/user/a/akveton/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /afs/cern.ch/user/a/akveton/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /afs/cern.ch/user/a/akveton/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /afs/cern.ch/user/a/akveton/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 1.99, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<2048<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'cms904usr' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /afs/cern.ch/user/a/akveton/.ssh/known_hosts:13
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Server not found in Kerberos database

debug1: Authentications that can continue: gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
akveton2@cms904usr's password: 
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
debug1: Local connections to LOCALHOST:1083 forwarded to remote address 127.0.0.1:1083
debug1: Local forwarding listening on 127.0.0.1 port 1083.
debug1: channel 0: new [port listener]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
```

Some more symptoms:

If i open two terminals, one where I perform the tunnel, and one with curl:

I type `curl --socks5 localhost:1083 http://cms904usr` into the second terminal, and I get:

> curl: (7) Failed to receive SOCKS5 connect request ack.

At the same time, the first terminal prints out

> channel 1: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused

If i type `curl --proxy localhost:1083 http://cms904usr` into the second terminal, I get

> curl: (52) Empty reply from server

and nothing in the first terminal.

If i try to connect using firefox, I get

> The proxy server is refusing connections

Comment: What is the purpose of this tunnel? Why forward local 1083 to remote SSH port?

Comment: I am using it to set up a two-hop ssh tunnel. This pc is the one in the middle.

Comment: Well, then show your second tunnel from this middle cms904usr machine to the final machine. This will help to locate the problem. It seems you are trying to connect to the second tunnel using 22 SSH port. It is a bit strange. You need root account at cms904usr to use priviledged 22 port for tunneling. Otherwise select a number of this port above 1024 for both tunnels, because it will work for nonroot account.